# Chrome DevTools Console Text Highlight Color is Black

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

For some time, I have my selected text [highlighted black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdrmG.png) on the dev tools console. I couldn't find anyway to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Started to bug me too, created an issue for it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1196786 - star it if you like

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, but I had the same problem and got around it by [installing a custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28316687/2221649). The style that answer links to is pretty similar to the default, except the highlight is visible.